# submitting only filled textbox values and discard empt textbox ih form php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have form which lists all the in stock products from database with price.User will add quantity , it calculated the amounts and submits the form. in the list there are 5 products. Each time user can fill any one or all the 5. While submiting, i want to get only quantity filled values to database. I am not getting how to do it

Here is my code

```
<tr>
        <td><?php echo $Myrow['product']; ?></td>
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="<?php echo Myrow['id']; ?>" />
        <td><input type="text" name="rte[]" value="<?php echo $Myrow['rate']; ?>"  readonly="readonly" class="price form-control" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Qty[]"  class="Qty form-control" /></td>
         <td><input type="text" id="amount" name="amount[]"  class="amount form-control" /></td>

       </tr>
       <?php } ?>
     </tbody>
```

How can is submit only non-emptied values. Please help

Comment: So check each quantity field has a value before updating the database in your PHP script

Comment: you can add required="required" to your input to make users fill in all the inputs

Comment: @RamondeVries Then all fields would HAVE to be entered and OP does not want that

Comment: @RiggsFolly oh i see. my fault

Comment: @RamondeVries :)

Comment: in your code to send the vales to your database make if statements to check if the inputs have an input bigger then 0, then only add the inputs that it outputs

Comment: if i have 5 products with product name and price, i enter quantity for only 2 items, so when i submit the form, i should get only those who has quantity greated than 0. Now all the listed products are getting submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could help you

```
$product_id=$_POST['product_id'];
$qty=$_POST['qty'];
foreach ($qty as $key => $value) {
 if($value){
    .... here you can save $product_id[$key], qty and other 
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tuhin, i got it!